# Angular.js How to update Body and Header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m using angular 1.5 and I´m trying to change the included css stylesheet when clicking an image on the page.
my code looks like:

```
angular
    .module('backendApp.pageMenu')
    .component('pageThemePanel', {
        templateUrl: 'components/page-theme-panel/page-theme-panel.component.html',
        controller: function (settingsProvider) {
            this.settings = settingsProvider;
            this.showThemePanel = false;
            this.setCurrentTheme = function (theme){
                settingsProvider.layout.currentTheme.title = theme;
            };                
        }
    });
```

So far, so good - the currentTheme is changing. But how can I replace the included css-File in the header? do i have to create an HeaderController or is it possible to set the file in an directive with a watcher function?

Question 2: How is it possible to change / add classes to the body? 
I´m working only with the settingsProvider and components until now. But the body isn´t "inside" these components. Do i have to use rootScope?!

Comment: Why do you want to include a different css-file? One approach might be to just add an extra css class in one of the top-divs of your page, and just overload the stuff you want changed when that class is applied in your css. Question2: it really depends on where you put your controllers and the ng-app. Everything within ng-app but not in a controller can be access trough the root-scope, but it should be no problem to just add a controller on the body tag to handle what you need

Comment: thank you for your reply. 1. The theme is divided in several css-files. So I´d like to load each css-file with an ajax request. 2. in a tutorial i read about not using controllers any longer and instead only use services and components.